# Why Am I getting the error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 parsererror?

Tags: php, json

All I have a form that submits data to a PHP file which inserts the post data into a CSV file, I'm upgrading this form to work with ajax so the user doesn't have to refresh the page upon a submission,

But I'm having an issue Im getting the **error**

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 parsererror

and Im not entirely sure what it means I've tested this form on the my dev server and it worked a charm and I copied it accross and made a few tiny tweaks the form ID its fields to validate etc, but now Im getting the error and Im not sure why, any ideas ?

```
  <form id="form2" name="form2">
    <div id="response"></div>
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name"/></td><td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="required" placeholder="Surname"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/></td><td><input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">
            <p>Safe Combination</p>
            <select name="number1">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <select name="number2">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <select name="number3">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <select name="number4">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <select name="number5">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                ...
            </select>
            <select name="number6">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                ...
            </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" name="submit"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function(){
                $('form#form2').submit(function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Get the Login Name value and trim it
                    var fname = $.trim($('#fname').val());
                    var lname = $.trim($('#lname').val());
                    var email = $.trim($('#email').val());
                    var postcode = $.trim($('#postcode').val());
                    // Check if empty of not

                    var valid = '';

                    if (fname  === '') {
                        //alert('First Name is empty.');
                        valid+ 'First Name is empty.'; 
                        //return false;
                    }
                    if (lname  === '') {
                        //alert('Last Name is empty.');
                        valid+ 'Last Name is empty.'; 
                        //return false;
                    }
                    if (email  === '') {
                        //alert('Email is empty.');
                        valid+ 'Email is empty.'; 
                        //return false;
                    }
                    if (postcode  === '') {
                        //alert('Postcode is empty.');
                        valid+ 'Postcode is empty.'; 
                        //return false;
                    }
                    if(valid != '') {
                        $('#form2 #response').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Errors - " + valid)
                    } else {
                        $('#form2 #response').removeClass('alert alert-danger').addClass('alert alert-warning').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Processing the form");
                        var formData = $('#form2').serialize();
                        submitForm(formData);
                    }
                });
            });

            function submitForm(formData) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'comp/checker.php',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    timeout:  7000,
                    success: function(data) {

                        $('#form2 #response').removeClass('alert alert-warning').addClass((data.error === true) ? 'alert alert-danger' : 'alert alert-success').html(data.msg);
                    }, 
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#form2 #response').html('Something else went wrong :/ ' + errorThrown + textStatus);
                    },
                    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {
                        $('#form2')[0].reset();         
                    }
                });
            }


        </script>
```

PHP File

```
    <?php
    //header('Content-type: application/json');
    sleep(5);

    //if (!empty($_POST)) {


        $date = date("d/m/Y");
        $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $postcode = trim($_POST['postcode']);

        $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
        $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
        $number3 = $_POST['number3'];
        $number4 = $_POST['number4'];
        $number5 = $_POST['number5'];
        $number6 = $_POST['number6'];

        $totalnumber = $number1 . '' . $number2 . '' . $number3 . '' . $number4 . '' . $number5 . '' . $number6;

        $list = array("$date, $fname, $lname, $email, $postcode, $totalnumber");

        $file = fopen("contacts_2.csv","a");

        foreach ($list as $line) {fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));}

        fclose($file);

        //HEADER TO INDEX.PHP


        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = "<p>Thanks for your feedback</p>";
        echo json_encode($return);
        exit();

    //} else {
    //  $return['error'] = true;
    //  $return['msg'] = "<p>Something went wrong, please retry in a few minutes</p>";
    //  echo json_encode($return);
    //  exit();
    //}

    ?>
```

Comment: Is code provided by you is complete code? Because, I'm not able to see `lname` in your `<form>`.

Comment: And, from where `crackcode` is defined in your `<form>` ?

Comment: try json_encode($return, 1);

Comment: lname is next to fname on the first line of the form, sorry that was a typo its called form2

Comment: tried json_encode($return, 1); same error

Comment: What does **echo json_encode($return);** statement print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you are receiving from the server is not a valid json. 
You are probably getting the response in xml format.
This could be due to an error being generated by the php page. Check if the response is generated by the php page. Also check if the php page has adequate permissions to execute on the production server.

Check the browser console to see the response generated by the php file.

Comment: Cheers I thought the permissions for the CSV file it was writing too would stay the same but apparently I have to have 777 permission on my CVS for it work, what is the correct file permissions to have on a writable CSV file

Comment: I have no idea what the correct file permission would be. 777 always gets the job done. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error:

> "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Solution:

- I was sending a number from javascript (via ajax with `dataType: "json",`) to php.
- What I didn't realize was that the number would be converted to a string before reaching the php.
- So, in order to use that sent value for doing queries etc. on the php side, I needed to convert it back to a number by using `intval`:

  `$gender = intval($_POST["gender"]);`

Answer (score 0):

If Wordpress try this function: `wp_send_json()` it worked for me.